# Upgrading HTML helper from asp.net mvc 5 to asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, html-helper, asp.net-core-2.0

I have some codes that have been written in `ASP.NET MVC 5` and now I want to use it in `ASP.NET Core 2`.
But It seems something are changed in `asp.net core 2` then I cannot use it.
I have a little experience  in `asp.net core 2`.
Please help me to compatible it with `asp.net core 2`

> MyHelpers.cshtml:

```
//Recursive function for rendering child nodes for the specified node

@helper CreateNavigation(int parentId, int depthNavigation, int currentPageId)
{
   @MyHelpers.Navigation(parentId, depthNavigation, currentPageId);
}

@helper Navigation(int parentId, int depthNavigation, int currentPageId)
{

   if ()
   {
       if ()
       {
         <ul style="">
            @foreach ()
            {
               if ()
                {
                   <li class="">
                      @Navigation(child.Id, depthNavigation, currentPageId)
                   </li>
                }
             }
         </ul>
      }
   }
}
```

> I call the method in _Menu.cshtml:

```
 @MyHelpers.CreateNavigation(rootNode.Id, 2,currentPageId);
```

Comment: Please state in detail any error messages you are getting.

Comment: @helper  ---> "The helper directive is not supported."

Comment: That error message appears to be entirely correct.  The Helper directive is not supported in .NET Core, and it appears that it will not be supported any time soon.  You'll have to find an alternative way to express your markup.  See [this Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q="The%20helper%20directive%20is%20not%20supported.") for more information.